# AngularJS Merge two JSON Response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

`$scope.addUserJson = $scope.adduser;`

`console.log($scope.addUserJson);`

**Output**

`Object {"username":"Mik911","firstname":"Mike","lastname":"Angel","email":"mik@gmail.com"}`

`$scope.usergroup = $scope.usergroupmodel;`

`console.log($scope.usergroup);`

**Output**

`[Object{"grpid":"1","username":"Vikram911","firstname":"Vikram","lastname":"Doe","email":"vik@gmail.com","gender":"Male",
"description":"BLAH BLAH","phone":"5858585"},{"grpid":"2","username":"Varun091","firstname":"Varun","lastname":"Doe",
"email":"varun@gmail.com","gender":"Male","description":"BLAH BLAH","phone":"898989"}]`

Merging two objects

`$scope.object = angular.toJson(angular.merge({}, $scope.usergroup, $scope.addUserJson));`

`console.log($scope.object);`

**Output**

`[{"grpid":"1","username":"Vikram911","firstname":"Vikram","lastname":"Doe","email":"vik@gmail.com","gender":"Male",
"description":"BLAH BLAH","phone":"5858585"},{"grpid":"2","username":"Varun091","firstname":"Varun","lastname":"Doe",
"email":"varun@gmail.com","gender":"Male","description":"BLAH BLAH","phone":"898989"}]`

How do I merge above two json response so that it should form the final result like below

`{"username":"Mik911","firstname":"Mike","lastname":"Angel","email":"mik@gmail.com","grpid":["1,2"]}`

Comment: You are merging an array with an object - you can not do that. You need to do that manually.

Comment: you should reply to our answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not just merge object with array or get only one field into the merge.

You can set grpid of the addUserJson object manually, in a single line, using JS array map function:

```
$scope.addUserJson.grpid = $scope.usergroup.map(function(grp) { return grp.grpid; });
```

Comment: How do I make it like `"listGroups":[
        {"id":"2"},
        {"id":"3"}
    ]` using above map function

Comment: Instead of returning grp.grpid in the map function, return {id: grp.grpid}

Answer (score 0):

I made it a bit more usable by considering the `$scope.addUserJson` to be an array...

If it is never going to be an array, notify me so that I can change it back to a single json object.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.usergroup = [{"grpid":"1","username":"Vikram911","firstname":"Vikram","lastname":"Doe","email":"vik@gmail.com","gender":"Male",
  "description":"BLAH BLAH","phone":"5858585"},{"grpid":"2","username":"Varun091","firstname":"Varun","lastname":"Doe",
  "email":"varun@gmail.com","gender":"Male","description":"BLAH BLAH","phone":"898989"}]


  $scope.addUserJson = [{"username":"Mik911","firstname":"Mike","lastname":"Angel","email":"mik@gmail.com"}];
  var result = [];

  // console.log($scope.usergroup);
  for(x in $scope.addUserJson){
   // console.log($scope.addUserJson.username +"=="+ $scope.usergroup[x].username);
   var temp=[];
   for(y in $scope.usergroup){

    if($scope.addUserJson[x].username.localeCompare($scope.usergroup[y].username)){
     temp.push($scope.usergroup[y].grpid);
    }
   }
   if(temp.length>0){
    var result1 = $scope.addUserJson;
    result1[0].grpid = temp;
    result = result1[0];
    temp=[];
   }
  }


  console.log(result);


 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
</body>
```